# How to have a high productivity in research in schools without a PhD program?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate

I was talking with a faculty member from Electrical Engineering department in a school that doesn't have a PhD program and she had some difficulties in finding students to work on research. How faculty in such schools can work on research if in general, undergraduates and Master students are not interested in doing research?

Comment: The field matters greatly... can you clarify? In mathematics, for example, faculty do not really-truly need undergrads or grad students to do research, although the interactions can be stimulating...

Comment: @paulgarrett in STEM fields

Comment: Ok, STEM, but still more detail is needed.

Comment: Can you clarify if the schools in question have a relatively high teaching load for faculty in your target area? My initial reaction to your colleague's observation is that she would like to involve students with research because she is teaching all the time and is not always able to keep her research program going because of that (and students who want to do research with her would ideally be able to devote more time, assuming they weren't also always busy with classes). Is that the case? If not, what is it? Is it related to a field-dependent issue? Something else?

Comment: @MadJack teaching load is 2-3 and can be 2-2 after getting a grant

Comment: “STEM” is far too broad, Research in high-energy physics is very different from research in fracture mechanics, which is very different from research in theoretical computer science, which is very different from research in genetics.

Comment: I agree with @JeffE that STEM is too broad, I also dont like that term anymore, bcs ppl are associating it with high employability rate. I think Thomas Lee need to advise her to change school, or to get affiliated with pther institutions

Comment: Electrical engineering